# Installing webkit for Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, qt, webkit, capybara

I'm trying to install webkit for Capybara, using the information provided [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit), but I'm getting an error.

Following the instructions I have tried to change the `qmake.conf` file in the `Qt` installation directory but I couldn't find the `QMAKE_IDC` parameter and I don't know where the following values should be placed:

```
QMAKE_RCC = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]$${DIR_SEPARATOR}rcc$${EXE_SUFFIX}
QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

The following error is what I got:

```
C:\Users\Deepzster\Desktop\app\app>gem install capybara-webkit
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
        ERROR:  Error installing capybara-webkit:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20141118-9536-wfpmna.rb extconf.rb
    Command 'qmake -spec win32-g++ ' not available

Makefile not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. I had installed the latest version of Qt, which is version 5.3. I looked up the instructions on https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit, and one of the instructions is to modify the `qmake.conf` file, and the edits are to be made after "the line beginning with QMAKE_IDC". However, this line wasn't available in my `qmake.conf` file.

Therefore, I installed the version stated in the instructions, which is version 4.8.5. Here's the link - http://download.qt-project.org/archive/qt/4.8/4.8.5/. I downloaded `qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-mingw.exe`  (I'm on a Windows 7 64-bit machine).

The `qmake.conf` file in this version does have the line beginning with `QMAKE_IDC`, so I could edit it as required. I then followed the rest of the instructions up to step 10 on the link (I also tried step 11, but I got a 'make failed' error). I then went to the directory containing my Gemfile and entered

```
gem install capybara-webkit
```

and the installation was successful.

Comment: Thank you so much! This actually worked for me. I've been trying so many different things but I couldn't find any solution to fix the problem. You are a star!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your qmake is added in system path, otherwise it will fail to install.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `qmake` utility on your workstation, as indicated by this message:

```
Command 'qmake -spec win32-g++ ' not available
```

I may suggest you to install [QT for Windows](http://www.qt.io/download-open-source/). If this already done here [suggested](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#windows) [readings](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/capybara-webkit/2tnnGLkrQkU).

Comment: I have already installed QT for Windows, following the same link. In step 5 of the link for Windows (Frommel Workaround), it asks to add a couple of lines to the qmake.conf file after the line beginning with 'QMAKE_IDC'. I'm unable to find that line in the file, so I'm not sure as to where I have to add those lines. These are the lines I have to add -
QMAKE_RCC = $$[QT_INSTALL_BINS]$${DIR_SEPARATOR}rcc$${EXE_SUFFIX}
QMAKE_LFLAGS = -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++

Comment: I've got version 5.3 of QT and the link you suggested describes the steps for version 4.8.5. Therefore, my paths are different from the ones mentioned in the steps. However, I am pretty sure I haven't got my paths mistaken. I'm just wondering if I'm supposed to edit the qmake.conf file differently from the way the steps tell me to, considering I've got a newer version.